# неправильно работает Datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

в Datepicker jquery  если писать вот так

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({

onSelect : function (e) {
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td').each( function () {
    if(-здесь проверяется совпадение нужного дня с текущим-){
    $(this).css('background','#F94545');
    }
    })
    }
});
```

то все дни которые нужны перекрашиваются в нужный цвет фона, а затем все пропадает, кто знает как исправить очень прошу помогите советом. Сначала все точно работает потому что если вывести alert то по каждому алерту видно что меняется фон в нужных датах, а когда алерты прекращаются фон исчезает с красного на тот что по умолчанию.

Comment: Начнем с того, что у вас неверно озаглавлен вопрос - Datepicker работает как раз нормально, а вот вы как раз пытаетесь неверным способом изменить его работу :)

Comment: а как будет правильно? и в чем ошибка?

Comment: не знаю как будет прям на 100% верно с datepicker, но лучше если бы ты добавлял этим элементам класс для подсветки даты, а классу уже через css стили добавил оформление.

Comment: фактически это так и есть, я просто здесь так написал но суть здесь в том что после этой функции что то происходит видимо дни перезагружаются и все слетает, и я не могу найти там событие загрузки чтобы переменять все нужные даты(

Answer (score 0):

Отвечая на ваш вопрос в комментариях, решать все нужно через стили самого datepicker, перезаписывая их, удаляя и тп. Ответ на ваш вопрос легко ищется в Google по запросу "datepicker current date color", например [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906266/how-to-change-the-cell-color-of-a-jquery-datepicker). Вам предлагается повесить обработчик на выбор даты и каждый раз обновлять цвет ячейки с текущей датой:

```
onSelect: function(value, date) {
    date.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a')
        .css('background-color', '#000000');
}
```

Comment: нет нет выбор текущей даты там уже происходит а нужно к примеру если у человека запись на консультацию 4 мая  и 10 июня при смене дат и месяцев менять фон на этих датах

Comment: @misha11 в смысле, что нужно просто некие даты (одну, две, неважно) подсвечивать на календаре, верно? Вне зависимости от того, являются ли они текущими (то есть является ли дата сегодняшним днем) и тп?

Comment: да да точно так, нужно чтобы подсвечивались дни назначеных консультаций, в месяц их может быть один или 10, если ставить событие на клик всего блока то переход по месяцам срабатывает но по клику на дни опять исчезает(

Comment: Тогда вы все равно можете использовать тот код, который я привел вам выше, в смысле что повесить на событие `onSelect` поиск всех нужных вам дат - и в итоге каждый раз, когда пользователь будет кликать новую дату, у вас будет исчезать нужная вам подсветка, но сразу же, незаметно для пользователя, появляться вновь. Либо вам придется лезть в код самого плагина, что не слишком верно методологически.

Comment: нет не срабатывает( если ставить так                                                                                                                                 onSelect: function() {
  $('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td').each(function() {
   alert($(this).html());
   $(this).addClass('active');
   })
 }

то по мере того как выводится алерт под ним видно что все даты закрашиваются в тот цвет который указан для класса active в цсс но как только алерты заканчиваются то все закрашенные даты становятся не по умолчанию а если просмотреть внутрь элемента у них нет класса active

Comment: onSelect: function() {
  $('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td').each(function() {
   alert($(this).html());
   $(this).addClass('active');
   })
 }

Comment: отформатировать скрипт не получилось вписал отдельно